# Oracle apex dynamic action on button click

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have created Oracle apex dynamic action to create text fields dyanmically, but the event fires only once. That is only once the text fields get created.

Comment: put some code here and highlight which line of code has issue.

Comment: Change the event scope to dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure i get what you are asking, but I can see to possible meanings:

1. You are using javascript to create new page items on each click, in which case I strongly advise against - the best practice would be to insert new rows into an interactive grid, which you can latter parse as a collection to do whatever you need
2. You still intend to create new items, look into the documentation of apex_items:
   https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/apirefs.32/e13369/apex_item.htm